# centralManagerDidUpdateState throws unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I have a view controller that starts a bluetooth scan when you push a button.

Here is the `.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import CoreBluetooth;

@interface ViewControllerIntroPage2 : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIButton *scanForFetchTagsButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *scanForFetchTagsButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CBCentralManager *mCentralManager;

-(IBAction)scanButtonPressed:(id)sender; 

@end
```

Here is the `.m` file:

```
#import "ViewControllerIntroPage2.h"
#import "BlueToothLEManager.h"

@interface ViewControllerIntroPage2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerIntroPage2

@synthesize scanForFetchTagsButton; 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)scanButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Scan Button Clicked");

    self.mCentralManager = [[BlueToothLEManager alloc]initializeCBCentralManager];

    NSLog(@"Scan Done"); 
}
/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Here is my the BluetoothLEManager files:

`.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@import CoreBluetooth;
@import QuartzCore;

@interface BlueToothLEManager : NSObject < CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (strong, retain) CBCentralManager *mBTCentralManager;

-(CBCentralManager*) initializeCBCentralManager;


@end
```

`.m` file:

```
#import "BlueToothLEManager.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation BlueToothLEManager


-(CBCentralManager*)initializeCBCentralManager{
    NSLog(@"initializing CBCentral Manager");
    return self.mBTCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}

#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

// method called whenever you have successfully connected to the BLE peripheral
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
}

// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI); 
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    NSLog(@"Start scan");

    if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        NSLog(@"Scanning for BTLE device"); 
        [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_NAME]] options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
    }
}
@end
```

The issue is that the app keeps crashing/pausing. Sometimes it will throw an `unrecognized selector sent to instance error`, but doesn't always happen. I've checked to make sure that there isn't an issue with the button, because when I remove the `self.mCentralManager = [[BlueToothLEManager alloc]initializeCBCentralManager];` the app doesn't crash.

Can anyone tell my why this crash is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems. Right now you are not keeping a reference to an instance of BluetoothLEManager, which means it will be deallocated shortly after you return from `scanButtonPressed:`, But that instance is still the delegate of CBCentralManager, depending on how CBCentralManager stores its delegate this might lead to a crash or it won't call any delegate methods. Delegate are normally not retained, so if the instance gets released CBCManager will either access invalid memory or it has set its delegate to nil.

Instead of keeping another reference to CBCentralManager in your ViewController you should keep a reference to an instance of BluetoothLEManager. That will solve your first problem, if you keep the instance around it won't be deallocated and the CBCentralManagerDelegate methods will be called correctly.

And you are using a wrong allocation pattern. In Objective-C if you call alloc you have to call the complete deal, e.g. `[[Class alloc] init]` or `[[Class alloc] initWithSomething:someThing]`. Methods that start with init have to return their own Class.

Those are the problems that I can spot for now.

I have fixed and modernized your code:

BTMgr.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@import CoreBluetooth;

@interface BlueToothLEManager : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
@property (strong, readonly) CBCentralManager *mBTCentralManager;
@end
```

BTMGr.m

```
#import "BlueToothLEManager.h"
//#import "Constants.h"

@implementation BlueToothLEManager

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"initializing BluetoothLEManager");
    _mBTCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

// method called whenever you have successfully connected to the BLE peripheral
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
}

// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    NSLog(@"Start scan");

    if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        NSLog(@"Scanning for BTLE device");
//        [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_NAME]] options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
    }
}
@end
```

VC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerIntroPage2 : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *scanForFetchTagsButton;

-(IBAction)scanButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

VC.m

```
#import "ViewControllerIntroPage2.h"
#import "BlueToothLEManager.h"

@interface ViewControllerIntroPage2 ()
@property (strong) BlueToothLEManager *bluetoothManager;
@end

@implementation ViewControllerIntroPage2

-(IBAction)scanButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Scan Button Clicked");
    if (!self.bluetoothManager) {
        // create if it doesn't exist
        self.bluetoothManager = [[BlueToothLEManager alloc] init];
    }
    NSLog(@"Scan Done");
}

@end
```

Comment: thank you for the wonderful explanation. I'm new to iOS programming, and I have a strong background in Android development, so this is all a bit new to me. Thank you for the well though response. If you know of any reading material or info that would help me get acclimated to iOS, I won't complain. Thanks again.